# Reference controller variable in HTML page

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets, view, controller

I have a number of view files (with .HTML extension) located in the WEB-INF directory of my Java servlet application.  I would like to be able to reference the variables that have been defined in the controller from within the view.

controller:

```
String email_address = ...
```

view:

```
<INPUT type='text' name='email' value='<%= email_address %>'/>
```

Unfortunately, the <%= %> syntax isn't valid.

What is the correct syntax?

** edit **

If it makes a difference, I'm referencing the HTML by:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/form_auth.html").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax for that; such functionality does not exist.

You need to put an object into scope in order to reference it in JSP. In your case, if you want to reference dynamic properties in an HTML file, you'd need to run the HTML file through the JSP processor (or other templating mechanism).

Alternatively, you can map `.html` URLs through the servlet mechanism, and use JSP (or other templates) as the actual implementation of the `.html` URLs.

These days this is not done via scriptlets (`<%= %>` syntax). This should be done using normal JSP EL (`${ }` syntax) and scoped attributes, generally the request scope.

For example, you could expose a single variable:

```
// Java:
// Java conventions would name this "emailAddress", not "email_address".
request.setAttribute("emailAddress", emailAddress);

<%-- JSP --%>
${emailAddress}
```

Or create a complete DTO object:

```
// Java
dto.emailAddress = "the@email.address";
request.setAttribute("dto", dto);

<%-- JSP --%>
${dto.emailAddress}
```

Comment: @lwburk Hard to say; if they're truly `.html` files, and unprocessed by the container, it certainly won't work as the OP hopes it will.